# Retrieve enterprise number from snmpget

Tags: snmp

I'd like to retrieve the unique enterprise number of a switch from an snmpget query

Is there any global OID to query?

I've tried with 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 that is nearly ok but I'd like to retrieve the unique number for the enterprise for example HP ---> 11

Thanks a lot

Comment: ok i solved problem with sysobjectid oid

Answer (score 0):

SysobjectID (or the OID 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0 ) is the way to get the unique enterprise OID. It is the number following the 1.3.6.1.4.1

Here is description from the MIB documentation

"The vendor's authoritative identification of the
network management subsystem contained in the entity.
This value is allocated within the SMI enterprises
subtree (1.3.6.1.4.1) and provides an easy and
unambiguous means for determining `what kind of box' is
being managed. For example, if vendor`Flintstones,
Inc.' was assigned the subtree 1.3.6.1.4.1.424242,
it could assign the identifier 1.3.6.1.4.1.424242.1.1
to its `Fred Router'."